# type object not subscriptable - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 from newsapi.sources import Sources
 import json
 api_key ='*******************'
 s = Sources(API_KEY=api_key)
```

they input the category of news they want

```
 wanted = input('> ')
 source_list = s.get(category=wanted, language='en')

 index = 0
 sources = []
```

getting the sources
     for source in source_list["sources"]:

```
     data = json.dumps(source_list)
     data = json.loads(data)

     source = (data["sources"][index]["url"])
     sources.append(source)
     index += 1


 from newspaper import Article

 i = len(sources) - 1
```

looping through the source list and printing the articles
     for source in sources:

```
     url_ = sources[i]

     a = Article[url_]  
     print(a)

     i -= 1
```

getting error 'type' object is not subscriptable on the line `a = Article[url_]` have researched but still do not understand why in my case.

Comment: @LucaCappelletti I think `newspapers` is a module. http://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: What do you intend to do while writing that?

Comment: im going to use it as part of another project im working on

Comment: and my code is just like the docs

Comment: This is a simple syntax error: `a = Article(url)` not `a = Article[url_]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple solution to your problem is that the line:

```
a = Article[url_]
```

Should be:

```
a = Article(url_)
```

Now to get to why you're getting the `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable` error.

This `TypeError` is the one thrown by python when you use the square bracket notation `object[key]` where an object doesn't define the `__getitem__` method. So for instance, using `[]` on an `object` throws:

```
>>> object()["foo"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'object' object is not subscriptable
```

In this case `[]`s were used accidentally instead of `()`s when trying to instantiate a class. Most classes (including this `Article` class) are instances of the `type` class, so trying `object["foo"]` causes the same error you are experiencing:

```
>>> object["foo"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Thank you so much , now i understand

Comment: Thanks for a good explanation for a simple but perplexing error.